# Get Current View Controller from NSObject Class file

Tags: ios

I have an `NSObject` file for detecting network connection. If its down, I will like to display an activity indicator at the top of the current view controller navigationitem. My storyboard config is a tabbarcontroller with three tabs. Each tab connect to multiple viewcontrollers through a navigation controller individually (i.e. each tab got one navigation controller).

I like to get current viewcontroller and display the activity indicator but failed to get e current display viewcontroller. I have tried the codes below but doesnt work. Can anyone advice me?

```
   UIViewController *topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
   UIActivityIndicatorView *aiView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
   aiView.hidesWhenStopped = NO; //I added this just so I could see it
   topViewController.navigationItem.titleView = aiView;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try this. I used this to display a view anywhere in my app from a NSObject file:

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *vc = [window rootViewController];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cab us `visibleViewController` property

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *currentVc=[window.rootViewController.navigationController visibleViewController];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you

```
UIViewController *currentVc = [(UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController topViewController];
```

**You must have used UINavigationController as the rootViewController for your UIWindow in the project.**

Answer (score 0):

please check your

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Most of the member failed to test it ,if you can use it then only window and UIViewController are able to access.